# Bootstrap 3 Make First Tab Active By Clicking From Outside Button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please let me know how I can make bootstrap First Tab active again by clickicking a button from outside of the tab-navs?

I alredy tried this

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#btnReview').click(function(){
  $(".tab-content").removeClass("active");
  $(".tab-content:first-child").addClass("active");
});
```

and

```
$('#btnReview').click(function(){
  $(".nav-tabs").removeClass("active");
  $(".nav-tabs:first-child").addClass("active");
});
```

but both not doing the job! Thanks

Comment: Proper way to use the `:first-child` is to define the type of child first. So if you want first `div` under `<div class="tab-content">`, then you have to use `".tab-content div:first-child"` as the selector. See [the specs](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.tab()` method like this:

```
$('#btnReview').click(function(){
    $('#tab1').tab('show')
});
```

I added directly an ID to the tab `<a>`, but you can play with another selectors:

```
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="tab1">Home</a></li>
```

From [Bootstrap Tab docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs):

**$().tab**

Activates a tab element and content container. Tab should have either a `data-target` or an `href` targeting a container node in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

After save successful for Twitter Bootstrap select first tab

```
$(".nav-tabs >li").removeClass("active");
$(".nav-tabs >li:first-child").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using similar case:

```
function btnOutside() {  $('#home').tab('show')     };

<button  href="#home" data-toggle="tab" type="button" id="Button1" onclick="btnOutside();">
```